# Strategies for using multiple external scripts in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm attempting to write SQL Server stored procedures that call external Python and R scripts using `sp_execute_external_script`. In the spirit of making my code modular and reusable, I'm writing a couple of stored procedures that are called from one another, as needed.

However, I'm running into a problem with having nested `INSERT INTO` calls, which SQL Server does not allow, since each script returns tabular output that becomes input for the next procedure. Specifically, I'm doing the following:

```sql
create table #table1 (...)
insert into #table1
execute sp_execute_external_script ...

declare @table_2_inputs = 'select col1, col2, ... from #table1'

create table #table2 (...)
insert into #table2
execute sp_execute_external_script ...
   @input_data_1=@table_2_inputs,
   ...
```

Is there a preferred strategy for doing this sort of thing that avoids nested `INSERT INTO` problems?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, creating something like a `work` schema, and then using real tables would ease a lot of the pain. And I hope beyond hope that `declare @table_2_inputs = 'select * from #table1'` isn't anything close to a real line of code, because SQL injection is real.

Comment: Yeah, none of this is real code. I'm just trying to illustrate my objective, but I will edit the example to get rid of it. Unfortunately I don't think real tables are feasible because I have to do this thousands of times and the information in these tables is not useful outside of being inputs for these stored procedures.